# Copying a Multi-Dimensional Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, copy, scanf

I have this homework question which I can't solve. I have to create a multi-dimensional array (of unknown size), fill it up, then copy it onto a new array. Here is what I came up with.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void copy_arr(int x, int y, double source[x][y], double target[x][y]);

int main(void){
int x,y,i,j;

printf("Enter how many rows you want? \n");
scanf("%d" ,&x);

printf("Enter how many columns you want? \n");
scanf("%d" ,&y);

double source[x][y];
double target[x][y];

for (i = 0;i<x;i++){
    for (j = 0;j<y;j++){
        printf("Enter a number. \n");
        scanf("%lf " ,&source[x][y]);
    }
}

copy_arr(x,y,source,target);
return 0;
}

void copy_arr(int x, int y, double source[x][y], double target[x][y]){
int i,j;

for (i = 0;i<x;i++){
    for (j = 0;j<y;j++){
        target[i][j] = source[i][j];
        printf("%.3lf " ,target[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

return;
}
```

I have 2 problems with this piece of code.

1. Input problem. When I enter the first value to add in the array, it doesn't read/store it. It reads/stores the previous variable on the following loop. This means that for a 2x2 array, I have to input 5 numbers, and the 5th one is useless (its ignored).
2. The copy doesn't work. It gives me values which are different than the ones I inputted. I have a feeling that it is passing the array, and its size, but not its contents (so its empty, hence the garbage output).

Anybody can guide me in the right direction please.

Thanks.

Comment: Excuse me, may I know if the ANSI C standard has relax the variable declaration to use variable as the dimension of array declaration now?

Comment: In C array takes continuous chunk of memory, so you can safely use `memcpy()`

Comment: @KenCheung It's a [variable length array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) and has been standardized since C99.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem 1:

You have the wrong indexes when calling scanf. Use i,j, not x,y:

```
    scanf("%lf" ,&source[i][j]);
```

Problem 2:

solved by solving 1.

**Note:**

Here is an alternative, shorter,  implementation of `copy_arr`:

```
void copy_arr(int x, int y, double source[x][y], double target[x][y]) {
    memcpy(target, source, x*y*sizeof(double));
}
```

Comment: Yes, noticed the problem -.-' But it doesn't solve problem 1 :S

Here is a screenshot. http://gyazo.com/e3ccd5d64ea2e3a67984a72b4d55666c.png

Comment: I just removed the space from the scanf. I think it was messing things up. The extra space will cause scanf not to read anything unless there is a whitespace after the number

Comment: Well that worked. I like to keep things more 'neat', so I try to add space, tabs etc. Thanks

Comment: Spaces and tabs in the right place makes the code easier to read. But if you put them inside strings they will affect the program.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a major problem:

```
scanf("%lf " ,&source[x][y]);
```

I think you mean

```
scanf("%lf" ,&source[i][j]);
```

The first one (that you have in your question) writes *always* to the same index, and it's beyond bounds of the arrays so it leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: That was obviously the mistake! -.-' Thanks. But it still didn't solve problem 1 :/

Comment: @The__Malteser Remove the space after the format code, it's not needed when reading numbers anyway (when scanning for string or numbers, `scanf` automatically skips leading whitespace).

Answer (score 0):

In `scanf("%lf",&source[i][j]);`

try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void copy_arr(int x, int y, double source[x][y], double target[x][y]);

int main(void){
int x,y,i,j;

printf("Enter how many rows you want? \n");
scanf("%d" ,&x);

printf("Enter how many columns you want? \n");
scanf("%d" ,&y);

double source[x][y];
double target[x][y];

for (i = 0;i<x;i++){
    for (j = 0;j<y;j++){
        printf("Enter a number. \n");
        scanf("%lf " ,&source[i][j]);
    }
}

copy_arr(x,y,source,target);
return 0;
}

void copy_arr(int x, int y, double source[x][y], double target[x][y]){
int i,j;

for (i = 0;i<x;i++){
    for (j = 0;j<y;j++){
        target[i][j] = source[i][j];
        printf("%.3lf " ,target[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! An extra space, and wrong variables! Thanks to all the posters. Quick and efficient as always :)